# AngularJS: JSON.parse(data).success is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js

I'm trying to use JSON.parse the data:**[{"id":"ABC123","provider_type":"Center","name":"Test1","phone":"03 2222 9999","mobile":"1111 123 123","email":"abc@gmail.com","address":["3999, Victoria","Est Danvale","113 HD streed","Block D, K House."]}]**

and code:

```
var callBackProviderSuccess = function(data){
        var providerObj = JSON.parse(data);
        if(providerObj.success) {
            $scope.providerInfo = providerObj.provider;
            $localStorage.providerJPayInfos = $scope.providerInfo;                IBMService.getStaffsOfProvider(providerID).then(callBackStaffsSuccess,callBackStaffsError);

        } else {
            $scope.infoLoadingText = "Provider not found on our database";
            //try again
            IBMService.getProviderById(providerID).then(callBackProviderSuccess,callBackProviderError);
        }  
    };
```

when debugging at  **if(providerObj.success)**, i have a message: **providerObj.success undefined**. Please help me give your thoughts.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is no `success` property inside the JSON .

Change it as,

```
if(providerObj) {
```